# Polymer using firebase query with context

Tags: firebase, polymer

in my custom Polymer element, i have a method that queries a firebase instance like so:

```
 _updateUser: function(user) {
        if(this._firebaseRef) {
          this._firebaseRef.off()
        }
        if(user) {

          var userLocation = ['xxxxx.firebaseio.com', 'users', this.user.uid].join('/');
          this._firebaseRef = new Firebase(userLocation);
          var query = this._firebaseRef.orderByChild("username")
          query.on("value", function(messageSnapshot) {
          messageSnapshot.forEach(function(messageData){
              this.set('usernames', []);
              console.log(this);
            });
          },null, this);

        }
      },
```

However, I keep getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function`. It seems that `this` is not set as the context as expected as per the [api documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html)

May I know how I can call `this.set` in my callback successfully? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the context into the `forEach` function as well.

```
messageSnapshot.forEach(function (messageData) {...}, this)
```

or

```
messageSnapshot.forEach(function (messageData) {...}.bind(this))
```